# I wanted to call index.cshtml from F#

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, f#

I'm trying to call index.cshtml because I'm thinking of building razor with F #.

If I debug this at this time I get a message like this:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Unable to find the required services. Please add all the required services by calling 'IServiceCollection.AddRazorPages' inside the call to 'ConfigureServices(...)' in the application startup code.'

```
type Startup() =
   member _.ConfigureServices(services: IServiceCollection) =
    (   services.AddRazorPages(fun options ->
            options.RootDirectory = "Controller" |> ignore
            options.Conventions.AddPageRoute("Controller/Index.cshtml","") |> ignore
    ))
// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
  member _.Configure(app: IApplicationBuilder, env: IWebHostEnvironment) =
    if env.IsDevelopment() then
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage() |> ignore
    else 
        app.UseExceptionHandler("\Error") |> ignore
        app.UseHsts |> ignore
    app.UseRouting()
       .UseEndpoints(fun endpoints ->
           // endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute().RequireAuthorization() |> ignore
            endpoints.MapRazorPages() |> ignore
```

The configuration of this solution is as follows:
[image]

Comment: I don't have much experience with Razor, so I'm a bit confused about what's going on here. Is this a Blazor/Bolero app? Are you trying to add a C# file to an F# project? I'm not sure that's even possible. If you could create a small app that reproduces the problem, that would probably help us debug it.

Comment: I'm new to programming and I'm using Visual Studio ,ASP.NET templates to start with "endpoints.MapGet (" / ", fun context->
                     I used to use a method like context.Response.WriteAsync ("<html> hello </ html>") |> ignore ", but I'm trying the current method by groping.